# Entity Framework: Creating entities from Oracle View

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I've been having this issue for over a week, and I know there are lots of questions about this, but I haven't seen one using Oracle. I'm using EF Database First, I need to create an entity from a Oracle View and because of the "You need to define a primary key" restriction, EF won't let me.

**Messages I've gotten:**

1. Key part 'COLUMN_NAME' for type 'VIEW_NAME' is not valid. All parts of the key must be non-nullable.
2. Warning Error 6002: The table/view 'VIEW_NAME' does not have a primary key defined. The key has been inferred and the definition was created as a read-only table/view.

**Work arounds I've tried:**

3. Modify de .edmx, and add the primary key myself. **RESULT:** The framework    will say "That column is nullable, we can't accept that"
4. Modify my view using the following syntax:

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW SCHEMA.MY_VIEW
   (COLUMN, FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3)
   AS 
   SELECT 
        NVL(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY FIELD1), 0) AS COLUMN
        , FIELD1
        , FIELD2
        , FIELD3

   WITH READ ONLY;

   ALTER VIEW SCHEMA.MY_VIEW
    ADD CONSTRAINT MY_VIEW_PK
     PRIMARY KEY
     (CODIGO_MONEDA)
     RELY
     DISABLE;
   ```

I've tried many version of the query above, adding NVL to the others field, creating a primary key. I just can't get it to work.

Comment: I immagine you are using DB First, is it?

Comment: @bubi yes, DB First. I'll edit the question adding that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unfortunetly I think there is no solution.
I have complained for that from the beginning of this year, EF Team has recognized that this is a bug but they cutted in the middle of the year all bug fixes for EF6 to develop EF Core.
See this link: http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2888

In fact, the problem is in the designer. I presume you are using Visual Studio 2015 ; that's why we are still using Visual Studio 2012 with EF 6.1.3.

We cannot migrate to Visual Studio 2015 without a fix.

I am very suprised that not so much people complained about that. It's just a killer point for .NET projects with Oracle databases.

Regards

Comment: You mean you guys work with VS 2012 and you can actually map entities without having a primary key defined?